# Verilog D flip-flop UP counter

Tags: logic, counter, verilog

Im making a simple up counter with D flip-flop in Verilog.
The module MUST be made with structural (Gates like AND OR NOT etc..)

```
module dff (Q,D, CK);
    input CK,D;
    output Q;

    wire NM,NCK;
    wire NQ,M;

nand DN1 (NM,D,CK);
nand DN2 (M,NM,CK);
nand DN3 (Q,NQ,NM);
nand ND4 (QN,Q,M);
endmodule
```

This is what I have got. But I failed to make working testbench even to test the DFF

```
module tb;
reg D, CK;
wire Q;
dff p0(Q, D, CK);
//jkstruct m0(q, qn, t, cp);
initial begin
    D = 0;
    CK = 1;
    #100;
    $display(Q);
    D = 0;
    CK = 1;
    #50
    $display(Q);
    D = 1;
    CK = 0;
    #50
    $display(Q);
    D = 1;
    CK = 1;

    $display(Q);
    $finish;
end
```

endmodule

Im newbie in this programming language so can you give me the examples please?

Comment: $display(Q); always show X whatever I do...

Answer (score 0):

Verilog allows a single bit wire to be inferred without a declaration. This can help reduce the number of lines of code but increases the risk of spiting a net with a type and never getting an error or warning. In this case, `QN` and `NQ` should be the same net.

FYI: You implemented a [D latch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#Gated_D_latch), not a [D flip-flop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#D_flip-flop).